# How to set a div over a div using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a div with list of data over a div(this div has google map).

So a list of Locations want to show in a div over google map div.

Html Code :

```
<div id="mapcan" style="width:100%;height:400px"></div>
<div class="air">
    <h3>Example project</h3>
    <ul class="nmap">
        <li id="_d0" class="bus_station">
            <div class="mlih">bus station</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Style code:

```
.air {
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1350px;
    left: 12px;
}
```

I am giving fix margin from top 1350px but if i added more content on above google map div list div goes to top so it's not properly work.

i want to fix it on google map div if added more content above or below from this div. This list div will not affect.

Comment: add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your "legend" div inside your map and give your map a `position: relative` style.

That way, the `absolute` position of the child will be `relative` to its parent, meaning it will stay inside the parent div, even if you add content above/below the parent div.

```css
#mapcan {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.air {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">content above</div>

<div id="mapcan" style="width:100%;height:200px">
  <div class="air">
    <h3>Example project</h3>
    <ul class="nmap">
      <li id="_d0" class="bus_station">
        <div class="mlih">bus station</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">content below</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you want to like this:
Wrap both div with main div and add relative position of main div. Then try this code:

```
<div class="map-section">
  <div id="mapcan" style="width:100%;height:400px"> map Div</div>
  <div class="air">
   <h3>Example project</h3>
    <ul class="nmap">
  <li id="_d0" class="bus_station">
 <div class="mlih">bus station</div>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.air {
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 12px;
}
.map-section{
  position:relative;
}
#mapcan{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Here is jsfiddle code : https://jsfiddle.net/aou5gmcv/

Answer (score -1):

Add `z-index: 0;` to the bottom div and `z-index: 1` to the top div
and add `position: absolute;` to both div's

Comment: position both divs absolute will not help if you want to add more content above / below the divs.